# Symfony4 deploy to shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, symfony, symfony4

I'm using symfony4. Everything works in dev. But there is less tutorial for prod. [How to deploy](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#b-configure-your-environment-variables) tutorial provides only less info  (No info about shared hosting)

Index.php prevents .env from reading the environment variables. Thats fine. But in Symfony2.x we can switch between env by app.php and app_dev.php front controllers. But in Symfony4 There is no such files only one index.php and an .env file

According to the deploy [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#b-configure-your-environment-variables) .

> How you set environment variables, depends on your setup: they can be set at the command line, in your Nginx configuration, or via other methods provided by your hosting service.

I'm using shared hosting, so the provider does not allow to change environment variables. If it is in my file, I can use it good.

Currently to overcome this problem, what i'm doing is,

```
$_SERVER['APP_ENV'] = "prod";
$_SERVER['APP_SECRET'] = "79cfa09223f91b1a195134019e0b17ac";
```

I added these two line at the beginning of index.php and bin/console file. I think this is not the correct way to do.

**Suggest me hot to deploy symfony4 (Even testing prod environment)**

Comment: Why do you not edit the .env file on your production server to set it to prod?

Comment: @Louis-MarieMatthews I think there must be an easy way. Do I have to change .env file to .prod (File name change) . Or What? APP_ENV=prod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `.env` file that is on the server to have `APP_ENV=prod` The `.env` file is for the specific machine, it is ignored by git, while `.env.dist` is tracked. So edit the .env.dist and commit it.

Put your project in the same dir as public_html as a sibling. Then remove the public_html dir and recreate it as a symlink pointing to your project public dir.

Rename `.env.dist` to `.env`.

Run `composer require symfony/apache-pack` it will create the .htaccess file and you should be good.

Worked for me on A2hosted server.

**Update 2019-06-28**

Just deployed to Bluehost, they finally upgraded to PHP 7. I deployed into a sub-domain using the same process as above except one change. I had to add the following line to the public/.htaccess file generated by apache-pack in order to enable PHP 7.1

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using apache server for production (Shared hosting). The easy thing is edit .htaccess file.

Add this at the bottom of .htaccess file

```
# ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
SetEnv APP_ENV prod
SetEnv APP_SECRET 79cfa09223f91b1a195134019e0b17ac
```

This will solve the question.

---

### These are the things I faced personaly, so to help someone,

And sometimes symfony4 throws error on php7.2 servers. To solve this, in .htaccess file add the following code,

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

This code automatically generated by my server. I think someone needs this.

---

At first I tried to deploy my app without .htaccess file. But this throws error, no output in production server. I tried to switch php and finally i saw the above code generated by server itself and later I added the setenv to work with symfony4.

Comment: Just a note concerning the error you mentioned with PHP 7.2: I'm using Symfony 4 on Apache with PHP7.2. Doing `composer require symfony/apache-pack` and making sure `mod_rewrite` was enabled was enough in my case.

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` located in the `public` folder? And can I change the `public` folder to `public_html`?

Comment: @Matt you can do by adding the following in composer.json "extra":{"public-dir": "public_html","symfony-web-dir": "public_html"}