# Symfony4 project deployment

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm working on my first symfony 4 project and i would like to upload it on my online server. My goal is to have it online on my domain to test it before a preview with my client.

I tried to put my files on the www folder (by ftp) and add a .htaccess in the main repository with :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>RewriteEngine On

# remove "www" from URI
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^devfuzz\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# use public as starting point
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]</IfModule>
```

And i added a .htaccess in public with :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried so many thing found on many forum but i have always the same with when i try to go on my website :

[website view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXCEw.png)

How can i change this view to have a normal navigation like i had with :
php bin/console server:run in local

Comment: which webserver (apache, nginx) in which version and which php (pfm, cgi etc.) in which version are installed on your "online server"?

Comment: My ovh server is on php 7.2 but i don't know my webserver version (and i don't really know if i have one installed)

Comment: so, then this might be your issue

Comment: That was my apache configuration. Sorry for the lost of time, i'm stuck in hell until the end of this project =P

Comment: You don't need to create the .htaccess yourself, use apache-pack. My answer here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949952/symfony4-deploy-to-shared-hosting/48970883#48970883

Comment: tried but didn't work =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your code with this one :

```
  # remove "www" from URI
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You don't need to remove the www in this part of code, this code will do it for you so do NOT change it :)