# How to fix symfony 4 http error 500 and run the website?

Tags: symfony, deployment, ftp, hosting

I have made a symfony website on my pc local (wamp) and now I want to upload it to hosting. I have created 000webhosting and Infinityfree hostings. Using FileZilla I had uploaded all of symfony directories inside my "public_html". It didn't work. I tried to upload everything in the root of "public_html" and the public folder into "public_html" folder. It doesn't work both ways.
**I get http error 500 message and the page isn't working. Also I don't get logs in my vars folder.**
Now I have uploaded all folders in the root and only public folder into "public_html" folder as described in this tutorial: https://medium.com/@runawaycoin/deploying-symfony-4-application-to-shared-hosting-with-just-ftp-access-e65d2c5e0e3d

**Note**: my php version is 7.2 and it is the same as hosting php.

**I have tried to do the following:**
1. Changed .env, .htaccess, index.php database information and wrote that APP_ENV=prod, not dev.
2. "composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
composer dump-autoload --optimize --no-dev --classmap-authoritative
composer require symfony/apache-pack" commands and then added again to ftp.
php bin/console cache:clear

3. changed location of require **DIR** bootstrap file (that bootstrap file contains path to vendor/autoload.php).
4. changed chmod to "var" folder to 775 or 777.
5. to framework.yaml file added assets parameter with path.

My index.php in "public_html" file code (***-hidden password):

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/../config/bootstrap.php';

$_SERVER[‘APP_ENV’]=’prod’;
$_SERVER['DATABASE_URL']='mysql://id9853857_nba1:***@127.0.0.1:3306/id9853857_nba'

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0002);

    Debug::enable();
}

if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

My .htaccess file (***-hidden password):

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

SetEnv APP_ENV prod
SetEnv DATABASE_URL 'mysql://id9853857_nba1:***@localhost/id9853857_nba'

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

framework.yaml code:

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #default_locale: en
    #csrf_protection: true
    #http_method_override: true

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: ~
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax

    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true

    assets:
        base_path: '/public_html'
```

I have tried a lot of solutions, googled a many pages and have already spent about two days to make this work. I hadn't imagined that it is so hard to deploy, I would have chosen laravel instead of symfony.
This is not very big page and I want it just on free hosting to get me and my friends to use it.

**FIXED by getting VPS, uploading there and configuring apache**

Comment: Look here, and pay attention to the symlink part https://stackoverflow.com/a/48970883/6127393

Comment: change  your APP_ENV to `dev` and post your error full message.

Comment: @ArleighHix I was trying symlink, made a cron job, but it still the same. Maybe I did something wrong, because it sounds like a good solution.

Comment: @AliKazemi changed to dev, but as I mentioned in my post I don't get any error logs. I mean my "var" folder is empty. I tried to chmod to 775 var folder, but still no log file was created.

Comment: if the 500 error is from Symfony, it should show the error in both browser window and error log. definitely you have error in your web server config.

Comment: @AliKazemi [link](https://imgur.com/TxoSz7d) this is what I get in the browser. In english it's like "This page is not working. nba2k14.000webhostapp.com at the moment can't handle a request. HTTP Error 500".<br>
And this is my var folder [link](https://imgur.com/PdycLJa), there is only cache folder.